# TextInput is not interactable when being used inside a view in a custom component (React-Native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've been trying to create a short form for users to fill out and it works in a pop-up component. While the buttons work, it appears that the the TextInput component inside isn't interact-able at all (no keyboard, nothing)

Here is my  code:

```
return (
        <View style={styles.page}>
            
            <View style={styles.button}>

                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button1} onPress={Something1}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonTitle}> Dome Something</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

                <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholderTextColor="black"
                />

                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button1}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonTitle}>Do something else</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>


            </View>

        </View>
    )
```

and here is my css styling:

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default StyleSheet.create({
  page: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF",
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    marginLeft: 0,
    marginRight: 0,
    marginBottom: 500,
    height: 300,
    width: 300,
    borderRadius: 100,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  button1: {
    backgroundColor: '#FFD8E6',
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    borderRadius: 5,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  buttonTitle:{
    color: 'black'
  }, 
  input: {
    height: 48,
    zIndex: 3000,
    width: 200,
    borderRadius: 5,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    backgroundColor: '#ADD8E6',
    marginTop: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
    marginLeft: 30,
    marginRight: 30,
    paddingLeft: 16,
},
})
```

Any clues? It's weird the buttons are clickable but not the TextInput. I am using the native TextInput with React-Native but 'react-native-gesture-handler' for the buttons

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full example of your code (no changes) working fine. Please provide more information if you're still encountering the issue. Cheers!

```
import React from "react";
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text, TextInput, StyleSheet, } from "react-native";


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    page: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF",
    },
    button: {
        backgroundColor: 'yellow',
        marginLeft: 0,
        marginRight: 0,
        marginBottom: 500,
        height: 300,
        width: 300,
        borderRadius: 100,
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    button1: {
        backgroundColor: '#FFD8E6',
        height: 100,
        width: 100,
        borderRadius: 5,
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    buttonTitle:{
        color: 'black'
    }, 
    input: {
        height: 48,
        zIndex: 3000,
        width: 200,
        borderRadius: 5,
        overflow: 'hidden',
        backgroundColor: '#ADD8E6',
        marginTop: 10,
        marginBottom: 10,
        marginLeft: 30,
        marginRight: 30,
        paddingLeft: 16,
    },
});



export default class App extends React.Component {
     render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.page}>
                <View style={styles.button}>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button1} onPress={() => { console.log('Do Something onPress()') }}>
                        <Text style={styles.buttonTitle}>Do Something</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.input}
                        placeholderTextColor="black"
                        placeholder="Placeholder text"
                    />
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button1} onPress={() => { console.log('Do Something Else onPress()') }}>
                        <Text style={styles.buttonTitle}>Do Something Else</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

[image: Code example as GIF]

Comment: If you're running in iOS simulator, make sure to select I/O -> Keyboard -> Toggle Software Keyboard to use keyboard. Common simulator gotcha!

Comment: I am using an Android. I think I am going to take a better look at what is going on with the Android side and report back.

Comment: Good luck! FWIW, may need to muck around with zIndex/elevation on your input.